Why it (the IF statement) worked?
There is a file with three columns. By default, status_column 3 has the status UP. But for some reason, the if statement does not work correctly.
while IFS=";" read -r ip_column1 name_column2 status_column3
do
    status=$status_column3
    if (ping -c 3 -W 1 $ip_column1 &> /dev/null)
    then
        status_column3="UP"
        echo $ip_column1$"-"$"success"
    else
        status_column3="DOWN"
        echo $ip_column1$"-"$"error"
    fi

    echo $status
    echo $status_column3

    if [[ $status != $status_column3 ]]
    then
        echo "Status is changed!"
    fi
done < <(tail -n +2 IP_test.csv)


RESULT:
10.1.0.218-success 
UP
UP
Status is changed! => WHY IT WORKED?
10.21.0.102-error
UP
DOWN
Status is changed


I tried to write code in different ways, but the essence did not change. It worked out as well.

Can you try echo "-$status_column3-" instead of your plain echo $status_column3 to see if $status_column3 does not contain trailing spaces?

echo $status echo $status_column3 echo "-$status_column3-"
result:
`UP
UP
-UP-
UP
DOWN
-DOWN-`

Try running the script under set -xv to see what values are assigned to variables and what commands are being run.

Thanks. Output: + '[' $'UP\r' '!=' UP ']'. If I can ask, how can I fix it? ---
`+ '[' $'UP\r' '!=' 'UP\r' ']' (new_line)

echo 'Status is changed!'-status_column3="UP\r"` it dont work.


\r is part of Window's newline "character". Windows uses \r\n while Linux uses just \n. Therefore bash (originally a Linux program) interprets the \r as a regular (but invisible) character. To solve the issue, convert your files (script and the csv) to Linux line endings using dos2unix.

The canonical question for that problem seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/6770384 here on stackoverflow. If that solved your problem, we can close your question here as a duplicate.

For debugging such a problem, you have to check what is stored inside your variables. echo is an unsuitable command for this. Do a xxd <<<$status instead, if you want to see the content of status.

Thank you all for the answers. I found a solution for myself:  status=\tr -d "[:cntrl:]" <<< $status_column3``. The question can be closed.
